# Android and Google Maps: Fading pulse animation

Tags: java, android, animation

I have created a pulse animation, that takes a location on a map, and continuously emits a pulse (circle). This works as expected. However, I would like the pulse to fade out, the further it is away from the point. Any thoughts on how to achieve this best?

The animation is as follows:

```
    mCircle = mMap.addCircle(
            new CircleOptions()
                    .center(mMarker.getPosition())
                    .strokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH)
                    .strokeColor(Color.parseColor(DEFAULT_COLOR))
                    .radius(RADIUS));

    mAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    mAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
    mAnimator.setIntValues(0, 100);
    mAnimator.setDuration(DURATION);
    mAnimator.setEvaluator(new IntEvaluator());
    mAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    mAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            float animatedFraction = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
            mCircle.setRadius(animatedFraction * SIZE);
        }
    });
    mAnimator.start();
```

Comment: I want to implement a similar solution without the drag. I need to show a pulse animation on a google map marker. Can you please post your solution as you have achieved that ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what you want can be accomplished with the provided [Google Maps Shapes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes).

My suggestion would be to do this with a [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html), [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), and [Ground Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay). You can redraw some shape on the canvas in each callback to `onAnimationUpdate()` and update the image on the ground overlay. Something like this:

**Init Bitmap / Canvas**
*(This could be the class contructor)*

```
private void init() {
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(MAX_ANIMATION_WIDTH, MAX_ANIMATION_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}
```

**Update Bitmap**

```
private void updateCanvas() {
    // Clear the canvas for new iteration of drawing
    mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

    // TODO: determine/update x, y, radius, paint as a function of animation progress
    // i.e. for a fade effect, set the paint color to a diminishing alpha level
    mPaint.setColor(mPulseColor);
    mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, mPaint);
}
```

**Update ground overlay**

```
private void updateOverlay() {
    mGroundOverlay.setImage(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mBitmap))
}
```

**Add Ground Overlay**
*(this is the `run()` method in the original post)*

```
private void addGroundOverlay() {
    // Add ground overlay with the bitmap's initial state
    mGroundOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions());

    // TODO: Set values for bitmap's initial state

    // Paint the canvas with the initial state
    updateCanvas();

    // Update the ground overlay
    updateOverlay();

    mAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            // Update animation values
            mPulseColor = Color.RED; // TODO: set color/alpha

            // Paint canvas with new animation state
            updateCanvas();

            // Update overlay
            updateOverlay();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Thank you!